# Monsters in Beyond: Two Souls

Tags: beyond-two-souls

**Possible Spoilers**

Where do the 'Monsters' come from in the scenes where Jodie is a little girl?

The monsters only seem to come out at night and they physically harm her, so it is not a bad dream or imagination. Also, they do not harm anyone else, even though they can. Finally, we see later in the game that the monsters come out of 'rifts' or 'condensers' connecting the human world with the infra world, but this seems to only happen after Jodie is already grown up.

Comment: You can put spoiler tags before spoilery bits.  Just start the paragraph with >!

Answer (score 1):

There have always been beings or monsters that can come through gateways and rifts, and not just the rifts created through the condensers.  The native american portion shows how they created a rift through a ritual where the giant evil sandstorm appears.. So it's needless to say that the condenser rifts were not the only way beings came into our world from the infra world.

Comment: Very good observation, but still quite doesn't answer my question about the monsters in Jodie's childhood because the monsters in almost every other scene (including Navajo) attack everyone else around them. Why do the ones in her childhood appear and target her specifically with seemingly no explanation? (not really meaning for that to be a separate question, just to show what I'm talking about and why, specifically, they are curious to me) At least the condensers, Navajo rift, and other rifts are explanations.

Comment: Most likely because she is the only person that can interact with the spirits... It seems maybe that she's a beacon for these beings.

Comment: Really she's not though, for instance other characters can talk to Aiden or get thrown around or possessed by them. It seems that the only thing different is that she can see them when others can't, but that should not stop the entities from interacting with them.

Comment: Well she's connected to Aiden, but yeah the other beings can attack / talk to the infra world beings in our world... But they may have been attracted to her first b/c of her connection to the infra world / Aiden